# Hide one div and show another?

Tags: javascript, css

I have two `divs` on called `#loading` and one called `#main`;

```
<div id="loading"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is with using javascript, show `#loading` for five seconds then after the five seconds hide the `#loading` div and show the `#main` div. The `#main` div is default hidden and once the `#loading` div is hidden the `#main` div shows.

I'm assuming that to achieve this would be a mixture of css and javascript; hopefully you understand what I'm trying to achieve and can help me accomplish what I'm trying to achieve.

Thankyou.

Comment: you can do `removeClass()` function in here.

Comment: and this should happen continously?

Comment: @Geeky just once on page load :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css would be:

```
#main {
    display:none;
}
```

The JS would be:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('main').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}, 5000);
```

Comment: is there a syntax error here? on your closing line you have two `}` and when I try to use this it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you out without the use of CSS. Only pure Jquery.

```js
$("#loading").show();
$("#main").hide();
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#loading").hide();
  $("#main").show()
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="loading">loading here..</div>
<div id="main" class="hidden">This is main content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";

    document.getElementById("main").style.display = "block";
  }, 5*1000);
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">loading</div>
<div id="main">main</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just curious, why do you have `#loading` in the CSS if you don't have styles to add?

Comment: I know it isn't needed, that's why I got curious to why you have it in there :p

Comment: Five sec only not the minute

Comment: Oh!..read it as 5 minutes..modified the code now it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
function loading(dur) {
  if (window.busy) {return;}
  document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById('main').style.display = "none";
  window.busy = setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('main').style.display = "block";
    window.busy = 0;
  }, dur);
}

loading(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I would avoid using ID's here as they polute the global.

You can do this nicely with CSS and classes..

```js
var holder = document.querySelector('.holder');
setTimeout(function () {
  holder.classList.remove('isloading');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.loading {
  display: none;
}
div.isloading .loading {
  display: block;
}

.main {
  display: none;
}
div:not(.isloading) .main {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder isloading">
  <div class="loading">Loading</div>
  <div class="main">Main</div>
</div>
```